# How to format numbers as Indian currency formats in MySQL

Tags: mysql, format

I want to format numbers from a column in MySQL in currency format with thousand, lakh separator with comma, it is formatting like thousand, million, etc but not that we do in [Indian formats.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for MySQL `Format`

Here is a example:
`select FORMAT(56687756,2,'en_IN')`